# Marine Ship voyage Period Dataset

Tags: data-request, transportation, oceanographic

Did anyone know, where can we find the dataset for approximate voyage period required for ship to travel from one port to another port(around the world) including the min & Max ship speed required for the ship?

Note - Includes all kind of Cargo ships except passenger ships

Comment: I ran across a really interesting research paper about the construction and population of such a database: http://glpf.org/sites/default/files/project_files/Dinesh%20pdf_Ship%20Data%20Extraction%20and%20Search.pdf

Comment: @BlairChristian You should post your comment as an answer, perhaps expanding or copying/pasting some more relevant parts.